# how did they get answer..differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cant figure out how did they get from the last step to the one I circled...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain rule.

The derivative of the LHS is:

$$(t^2 \ln t)'  = 2 t \ln t + t^2 (1/t) = 2 t \ln t + t.$$

Substituting $y(t)$ and simplifying the RHS gives us:

$$\dfrac{2(t^2 \ln t)}{t} + t = 2 t \ln t + t.$$

See how the LHS = RHS after the calculations, hence, this is a valid solution.

Comment: omggg I forgot calculus!!!!!!....need to go over it again...that makes sense...

Comment: it requires 15 reps to do it :(...can someone vote up if you are looking at this answer please...I'll do it when I get to it...thanks for help!